# Beginner - Java 2D Array

Tags: java

I've created the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class morse5 {

public static void main(String [] args)
{     

  //Declare Variables
  String [][] myIndexAlphaMorse = {{"a", ".-"}, {"b", "-..."}, {"c", "-.-."}, {"d", "-.."}, {"e", "."}, {"f", "..-."}, {"g", "--."}, {"h", "...."}, {"i", ".."}, {"j", ".---"}, {"k", "-.-"}, {"l", ".-.."}, {"m", "--"}, {"n", "-."}, {"o", "---"}, {"p", ".--."}, {"q", "--.-"}, {"r", ".-."}, {"s", "..."}, {"t", "-"}, {"u", "..-"}, {"v", "...-"}, {"w", ".--"}, {"x", "-..-"}, {"y", "-.--"}, {"z", "--.."}, {"1", ".----"}, {"2", "..---"}, {"3", "...--"}, {"4", "....-"}, {"5", "....."}, {"6", "-...."}, {"7", "--..."}, {"8", "---.."}, {"9", "----."}, {"0", "-----"}, {" ", "|"}}; 


  //Test
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myIndexAlphaMorse));
  System.out.println(myIndexAlphaMorse[8][0]);


}
```

What I would like to know is how to get the value of the corresponding position based on user input. I'm learning, so I just want the piece on how to get, as an example, `.-` back when `"a"` is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate over you array and compare the 0th element at each position with the character you are looking for.

```
String input = "v";
String result= "";
for(int i = 0; i < myIndexAlphaMorse.length; i++){
    if(myIndexAlphaMorse[i][0].equals(input)){
        result = myIndexAlphaMorse[i][1];
        break;
   }
}
System.out.println("morse for " + input + " = " + result);
```

But as the other answer says you should use a map that whould fit perfect for this task.

Comment: This is probably closer to the intent. I've learned for loops. I'll give this a try.

Comment: This works! Thank you all for your help and quick responses. I'm sure all of the answers were correct; I just needed the one at my low level!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a `Map` instead of a two dimensional array for this problem:

```
Map<String, String> myIndexAlphaMap = new HashMap<>();
myIndexAlphaMap.put("a", ".-");
myIndexAlphaMap.put("b", "-...");
// etc.

// given user input of "a" you can access via
myIndexAlphaMap.get("a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a map of string arrays

```
Map<String, String[]> myIndexAlphaMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
myIndexAlphaMap.put("a", new String {".","-"});
myIndexAlphaMap.put("b", new String {"-",".","."});

// given user input of "a" you can access via
myIndexAlphaMap.get("a")[0];
```

Comment: I haven't learned maps, yet. I think the point of this exercise is for me to learn how to take an entered value and, using either a 1D or 2D array, return the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Hash tables, since they've already given sample above of HashMap/Map:

```
Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
table.put("a", ".-");
table.put("b", "-...");
```

It is also synchronized and thread safe unlike HashMaps, albeit is a smidgen slower for bigger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to read the letter as the String object. Then you can just iterate through your array and when we find what we are looking for - just print it and break the loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String letter = scanner.next();
for (int i=0; i<myIndexAlphaMorse.length; i++)
    if (myIndexAlphaMorse[i][0].equals(letter)){
        System.out.println(myIndexAlphaMorse[i][1]);
        break;
    }
```